# Modbus Vs CANopen - Which one should I choose?

Tags: can, rs485, modbus, canopen

Modbus Vs CANopen - Which one should I choose if I want:

- Broadcast to all units
- Talk to specific units
- Robust
- Send lots of data
- Implement for embedded systems
- Easy to use
- Using in new projects with latest hardware on the market
- Secure that new industrial components talking the same protocol as I do

Comment: Very important consideration: availability of MCUs with built-in CAN bus protocol engine.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you! So you would consider CANopen rather than Modbus if you had to choose?

Comment: Try and find an MCU with a CAN bus engine. Good luck.

Comment: Why Modbus or CanOpen rather than ASi or EtherCat? Modbus is the base level digital protocol and is dead easy to implement but it is hardly what you'd call leading-edge.

Comment: @Andyaka STM32?

Comment: @Kartman I don't know. I just wonder which one is better to focus on? Modbus or CANopen if you would create a new project from the beginning?

Comment: @MrYui I'm asking you because, as far as I know, pretty much all the CAN bus engined MCUs are on long supply times.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't know what you mean by "long supply times". But as far I know, CAN is implemented in most modern microcontrollers.

Comment: Long lead times, difficult to buy, not in stock, not available etc..

Comment: @Andyaka Ok, I don't know nothing about that. I just buy a processor and that's it. I only use STM32 and all them have CAN.

Comment: If you have got one already then fine.

Comment: @Andyaka But what do you prefer. Modbus or CANopen if you have to choose between two products? One have Modbus and the other one have CANopen.

Comment: Ah, here's the problem, asking what people's opinions are makes the question off-topic. Reason: this is a Q and A site and not a forum. Also opinions are only relevant when there is enough background information to substantiate an answer and then, it's an answer and not an opinion. Basically, all I can say is that some jobs will need CAN and some jobs will use MODbus and some jobs will use RS485 and some jobs will use something totally different.

Comment: @Andyaka Well. I'm not here to ask for a personal opinion. I'm hear to ask about the market status.

Comment: But **YOU ARE** asking for opinions in your question. Asking about the market status is also probably off-topic too.

Comment: Regarding out of stock, then don't use STM32 if you are starting up something new, because they are currently impossible to purchase. It has nothing to do with CAN.

Comment: @Lundin I know that ST have problems with their delivery due to lack of semiconductor in the market. But there is ALOT of STM32 on Mouser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, Modbus is very old stuff and getting phased out everywhere. The only advantages it got is far less complexity than CANopen, plus that UART is more widely available.

To address your specific concerns:

> Broadcast to all units, Talk to specific units

CAN is generally more suitable for this, since it isn't a traditional master/slave system, but individual nodes can easily talk with each other while ignoring everything else on the bus.

> Robust

This is the biggest advantage of CAN, it is incredibly robust, even when compared to RS-485.

> Send lots of data

Depends on what "lots of data" means. There's nowadays the modern CAN FD/CANopen FD if you truly need high bandwidths.

> Implement for embedded systems

Both of these buses are for embedded systems.

> Easy to use

No field bus is easy. CANopen is very complex but generally you only use some 10% of all features available. Stripped-down, non-compliant CANopen solutions with reduced features is often a good compromise.

> Using in new projects with latest hardware on the market

CANopen/CANopen FD. Definitely. The latest hardware would be Cortex M micros with on-chip CAN FD compatible controllers, interfaced with CAN FD compatible CAN transceivers. One example would be Microchip SAMC21 together with MCP2562FD transceivers. These can run classic "high speed" CAN as well as CAN FD.

> Secure that new industrial components talking the same protocol as I do

That's very vague. CANopen is commonly used in industrial automation. The most  common UART-based one isn't Modbus but Profibus. Which like Modbus is old technology getting phased out.

Comment: Thank you. I totaly agree with that Modbus is only used because it's easy, not excellent.